# Django - Can't register a tag library

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Disclaimer: I'm a Django (and Python) beginner.

I've currently got a TemplateSyntaxError, where in order to use my Model's data in my template, I need to apparently register and load it first as a new tag. I've tried to do that in several ways but can never escape an error.

Here's my setup:

My folder structure:

- appapp

  - migrations
  - templates

    - index.html
  - templatetags

    - __init__.py
    - invite.py
  - __init__.py
  - admin, views, models, urls etc

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<code>[0-9]+)/$', findCode, name='index'),
]
```

views.py

```
def findCode(request, code):
    invite = get_object_or_404(Invite, code=code)
    temp = loader.get_template('appapp/index.html')
    context = {
        'invite': invite,
    }
    return HttpResponse(temp.render(context, request))
```

models.py

```
class Invite(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=6, default=code_generator(4))
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.group_name
```

index.html

```
{% if invite %}
    {% invite.group_name %}
{% endif %}
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to display the `group_name` value in the template, use `{{ value }}` syntax instead:

```
{% if invite %}
    {{ invite.group_name }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Yep, this was the exact problem. Thank you!